# Chaining statements together with commas

Tags: ruby

It's a really simple question, and I didn't find a good explanation. I know that it's possible chaining statements with semicolons, but I found some codes using commas. For example:

```
def gcd(a, b)  
  a, b = b, a%b  until b.zero?  
  a  
end
```

This method calculate the greatest commom divisor between two numbers. I understand the logic behind this calculation, but someone can please explain me how that is happening with this sintax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not actually chaining statements, it's parallel assignment. It means: assign the value of `b` to `a`, and assign the value of `a%b` to `b`, *at the same time*.

Because the values are interdependent, it can't simply be written as:

```
# WRONG
a = b
b = a%b
```

You'd need a temporary variable:

```
# Correct, but more verbose and less readable
old_b = b
b = a%b
a = old_b
```

The same syntax is also useful when destructuring arrays, for example:

```
my_array = [1,2,3]
a, b, c = my_array
```

Comment: ...and *parallel assignment* (sometimes called *multiple assignment*) can be combined with *disambiguation*: `my_array = [1,2,[3,4]]; a, b, (c, d) = my_array; a #=> 1; b #=> 2; c #=> 3; d #=> 4`.

Comment: You can also use parallel assignment to return "multiple values" from a method.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a guard clause.

Basically, a guard clause is a conditional statement which enables or prevents a block or line of ruby code from executing based on the conditional.

Most languages have a paradigm as follows:

```
fn mymethod do
   if somecondition
       return calculation
   else
       return error
   end
end
```

Ruby allows you to restructure the above as:

```
def mymethod
    return error unless somecondition
    calculation
end
```

I.e if the guard clause triggers, return the error, otherwise perform the default action of the calculation.

In your case, the guard condition is a loop instead of a single condition.